# Safest way to use and store User's third party credentials

Tags: security, github

I'm working on an add-in that will integrate git into the VBA IDE. I'm using the [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) library under the hood, which supports [User name and password credentials](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-fetch), but not [SSH Keys](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys). I would use GitHub's SSH Keys if the library supported them, but it doesn't.

So, I can easily enough ask the user for their credentials prior to trying to interact with the remote repository, but I can feel the "bug" reports coming in already.

> Why do I have to provide my password every time I try to push to my repo?

So...

**Question 1:**

Is it safe and acceptable to keep the password in memory after the user has entered it the first time? If there are caveats to that being safe or unsafe, what are they?

**Question 2:**

I can also see users not wanting to keep entering their password even on the *first* time they push during a session. Would it be safe enough to *encrypt* (not hash) the user name and password and store them along with the add-in's other configuration settings?

I mean, Visual Studio doesn't ask me for my GitHub credentials each time I start up the IDE, so it must be possible to do this relatively safely. But ***how***?

---

I have read through [many related questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=relevance&q=store%20a%20password%20is%3aq), but feel no closer to knowing how to go about safely using my users' credentials in my add-in. Most of the existing questions relate to websites and databases, where the right answer is "don't store the password in a recoverable way, salt and hash it and store the hash only", but in this instance, it's not a password to **my** service. I need to secure it the best I can, but in a recoverable way. Otherwise, there's no way my program can "log into" their repository on their behalf.

Comment: For a native app you can use the Windows Credential Manager by calling into native code as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435561/encrypting-credentials-in-a-wpf-application). For Windows Store Apps you can use [the Password Vault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465069.aspx).

Comment: Can't you get an OAuth token for Github, like Hub does? https://github.com/github/hub#configuration

Comment: I don't know @RobinWinslow, but I'll be looking into it.

Comment: @RubberDuck In .NET you could use SecureString class to store creditinals in memory. read more on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Vlad that's exactly what I did. [I had to create a patch for the library to add support though](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/90881/41243).

Answer (score 1):

The *safest* way to "store User's third party credentials" is to not store them - if you store them, you have two **major** issues:

- they may change before you update your cache of them (seen this several times)
- your app could be compromised, compromising unknown numbers of users' third-party creds

And probably many more.

You either need to use a different system (OAuth, OpenID, LDAP/AD, SSH keys, etc), or you need to get the user's credentials *every* time they want to use them.

Saving them is only going to cause you heartache down the road.

Comment: This may sound naive, but is there really that much risk to storing them for the duration of the session? This isn't a web app. The user's machine would already have to be compromised for anyone to attack my plug-in.

Comment: Also, as I pointed out, the library I'm using doesn't support other methods of authentication.

Comment: @RubberDuck - it's [relatively] trivial to read a program's memory and find actively-used data. You should ***always*** assume the machine you are running on is compromised - it's Security 101.